# Problems with missing out NAs from my data summary using plyr in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I am trying to summarize my data using plyr in order to present it in a graph using ggplot2. I used the function (quoted below) which I found on the R cookbook on a set of data that had no missing values and it worked perfectly, however ever since I tried it on a dataset with missing values, it does not work, the outputs for density returns NA for "Density" (aka mean) but not for N, SD or SE). I have tried changing the na.rm= clauses to TRUE, but that hasn't helped.  Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here ?

I will also include an image of the formatting of the excel file I am importing into R.

Many thanks.

```
summarySE <- function(data=NULL, measurevar, groupvars=NULL, na.rm=FALSE,
                      conf.interval=.95, .drop=TRUE) {
  library(plyr)

  # New version of length which can handle NA's: if na.rm==T, don't count them
  length2 <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x))
    else       length(x)
  }

  # This does the summary. For each group's data frame, return a vector with
  # N, mean, and sd
  datac <- ddply(data, groupvars, .drop=.drop,
                 .fun = function(xx, col) {
                   c(N    = length2(xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     mean = mean   (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     sd   = sd     (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm)
                   )
                 },
                 measurevar
  )

  # Rename the "mean" column    
  datac <- rename(datac, c("mean" = measurevar))

  datac$se <- datac$sd / sqrt(datac$N)  # Calculate standard error of the mean

  # Confidence interval multiplier for standard error
  # Calculate t-statistic for confidence interval: 
  # e.g., if conf.interval is .95, use .975 (above/below), and use df=N-1
  ciMult <- qt(conf.interval/2 + .5, datac$N-1)
  datac$ci <- datac$se * ciMult

  return(datac)
}
ggplotdata <- summarySE(data, measurevar="Density", groupvars=c("Genotype", "Region"))
```

[image: Original file formatting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem ! I realised that I had to **leave the cell blank** rather than typing NA in excel, (and change na.rm=T).